# How to set loop.index + pagination.skip for skipped values in loop

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a variable data and the format of data in it's data is as:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e158e32e6facf7181cc3fcc"),
    word: "aced ia",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e158e38e6facf7181cc4f93"),
    word: "acetal",

  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e158e31e6facf7181cc3e7f"),
    word: "acetic",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e158e38e6facf7181cc4f3f"),
    word: "ac etin",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e158e36e6facf7181cc48db"),
    word: "acetum",
  }
];
```

For displaying all the words I was doing as:

```
{% for word in data %}
    {{ loop.index + pagination.skip }}
    {{ word['word'] }}
{% endfor %}
{{ pagination.links }}
{{ pagination.info }}
```

But now I don't want to display the words which has spaces in `word['word']` , so I tried as:

```
{% for word in data if not ' ' in word['word'] %}
    {{ loop.index + pagination.skip }}
    {{ word['word']|e}}
{% endfor %}
{{ pagination.links }}
{{ pagination.info }}
```

But here the pagination information goes wrong(displays less number of words than displayed in pagination info) as in Image (I have added anchor tag and some styling *ignore)

[image]

Here it shows `displaying 81-100` but results are from `81-98`

....May I Know how to get this corrected , Am I doing wrong somewhere please let me know

Any help is appreciated , TIA

Comment: how you get data? from `db`? using `orm`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I am getting data from db

Comment: show how please

Comment: as i mentioned in  Q , in data variable

Comment: ok. show how you `render` please

Comment: You should filtrer your data and creating your pagination before sending them to the template.

Comment: @CharlesR Okay sure , this makes sense

Comment: @DanilaGanchar sure mate ,Query db store the cursor's in a list in a variable (data) and then `return render_template('test.html',data=data,pagination=pagination)`

Comment: @Codenewbie as I understood, `pagination` in your case is something like [object created using sql-query](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination). So you need to rewrite `sql` as recommend *CharlesR*

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yeah mate , I understood ....Thanks for looking in to this Q